# Identify subset of population to match given moments

Tags: sampling, density-function

- I have a Gaussian probability density function $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$. The mean and the standard deviation of this pdf is known.
- I have an unknown probability density function $g(x)$. I only know $g(x)$ by its $n$ realizations $\{X_1, X_2,..., X_n\}$.
- $g(x)$  is different from $f(x)$ but the density functions are expected to look somehow similar.

I would like to select a subset of $\{X_1, X_2,..., X_n\}$ composed of $m$ realizations (with $m<n$ and $m$ being specified by the user), that approximate best $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$. In other terms, I would like to select the $m$ realizations from $g(x)$ that lead to the subset which has the closest mean and standard deviation from $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$. Also, while $g(x)$ is probably not Gaussian, a subset of the $n$ realizations can be assumed to be Gaussian.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to use a forward greedy algorithm.

1. Select $X_i$ that is the closest from $\mu$. (subset size = 1)
2. Try individually the all $n-1$ realizations with the previously selected $X_i$ and compute  mean and standard deviation of the subset (subset size = 2)
3. Keep the realizations that lead to values that are the closest to $\mu$ and $\sigma$
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until subset size reaches $m$

I think the forward algorithm is not adatped at all to this problem. I believe that more soffisticated methods exist to solve this problem but I couldn't find any.

Comment: First off, you have a bi-objective optimization problem (close in mean, close in variance), so there will be a collection of "non-dominated" solutions known as a Pareto frontier.  While the greedy algorithm may not be optimal, we might be able to bound how bad it performs. Would that be meaningful for you?

Comment: I didn't detail much the forward greedy algorithm because I thought that it was really sub-optimal to solve this problem. If I eventually need to resort to a greedy algorithm, I will overcome the bi-objective issue by using a criterion such as Wasserstein metric (the earth mover's distance) that summarize the statistical distance by a scalar.